# Запомнить выбор кнопки confirm

Tags: javascript

Привет.

В окне `confirm` есть две кнопки **OK** и **Отмена**, помогите исправить скрипт что бы после нажатия на кнопку **Отмена** окно Alert не появлялось сутки.

Я применил для этого куки, но почему-то не срабатывает?

```
if (confirm("Выбор")) {
  // кнопка OK
  document.location.href = "http://..."   
} else {
  // кнопка Отмена
  setCookie("что здесь должно быть?", "что здесь должно быть?", 10);
}

function setCookie (name, value, seconds) {
if (typeof(seconds) != 'undefined') {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (seconds) * 86400);
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
}
else {
    var expires = "";
}

document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
```

}

Comment: Может стоит попробовать локальное хранилище  
localStorage.setItem('time', +new Date);//сохранение даты при нажатии кнопки отмена  
new Date(parseInt(localStorage.getItem('time')));//получение даты из локального хранилища для проверки на прохождение суток

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И *name*, и *value* внутри функции setCookie нужно пропускать через encodeURIComponent при формировании строки *name=value*.

```
function setCookie (name, value, days) {
    if (typeof days != 'undefined') {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days) * 86400);
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        var expires = "";
    }

    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

Нужна ещё фунция getCookie

```
function getCookie(name) {
  var matches = (document.cookie || "").match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
  ));
  return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : null;
}
```

А сама логика должна быть примерно такой:

```
if (getCookie("user_canceled") != "YES") {
    if (confirm("Выбор")) {
        // кнопка OK
        window.location.href = "http://..."   
    } else {
        // кнопка Отмена
        setCookie("user_canceled", "YES", 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите функцию полностью пожалуйста.

Comment: поправил функцию

Comment: Не работает, смотрите сами http://demo.pixelcom.crimea.ua/javascript/alert.html

Comment: Ну естественно, если устанавливать значение куки и нигде его не считывать, не использовать :-)
Доработал остальную часть.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Запускать при нажатии отмены

```
localStorage.setItem('time', +new Date);//сохранение даты в локальное хранилище
```

При проверке *показывать/не показывать* алерт если прошла секунда с момента нажатия кнопки отмена

```
if( !localStorage.getItem('time') || (localStorage.getItem('time') && +new Date - new Date(parseInt(localStorage.getItem('time'))) > 1000) ){
    alert('message');
}
```

Comment: localStorage - не все браузеры поддерживают. Как сделать с куки?

Comment: @Viher, А есть ли смысл поддерживать предсмертные конвульсии браузеров, которые не поддерживают хранилище? Доступ к кукам (и их установке) через `document.cookie`.

Comment: @TheDoctor то что написал arkada38 не работает даже в новых браузерах.

Comment: @Viher, Как это не работает? Может ты плохо ищешь? Это даже пару лет назад работало, тем более сейчас.

Comment: @arkada38 не показал логику, кроме этого нужно уведомление.  if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
    //использовать Local Storage объект для хранения данных
 } else {
  alert('Данные не сохранятся, ваш браузер не поддерживает Local storage');
 } В общем не то...